# Add ECO tags to questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Would there be any benefit to tagging questions about openings with the opening's ECO code?

It seems like this would be more advantageous if there were many more questions, but the tag wiki for the ECO code might be a good place to put a summary for the opening as well as some topical variations.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are some benefits.  For example, if I want to follow all questions asked about Alekhine's Defence, I only need to subscribe to tags B02 to B05, though this would require consistent/proper tagging.

Comment: This is a great idea.  The only problem I see is someone using the wrong ECO code, but I guess that is what editors are for.

Comment: So should we go ahead and do it? Anyone have an Encyclopedia? I'd be glad to help with the upkeep and editing, but I'm not as yet very familiar with the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad idea, but the taggers need to aware of the nuances of ECO: A00 is generally useless, while E97 may not be adequate to represent the thick wedges of theory that falls under it.